# Ensure the availability of a pool of stopped ec2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, automation

I want to maintain a pool of stopped amazon ec2 instances. Whenever the amount is below the threshold, I would like to be able to create new instances and then immediately stop them once they are running. Is this possible within the amazon infrastructure alone?

Comment: Could you please provide information about *why* you wish to do this? There might be a better way of achieving your goal (eg using Auto Scaling to launch new instances when required).

Comment: The time to start a stopped instance is much shorter than the time to create a new instance.

Comment: So, you're looking for a fast way to scale-out? Have you considered the [Amazon EC2 Container Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/Welcome.html)? It can deploy containers (eg with your application) in mere seconds. What difficulties are you currently encountering that makes launching an instance too slow? Are you using a fully-configured AMI when launching instances? Are you using Linux or Windows?

Comment: Yes, we have considered rolling out to using docker, however, that is going to take a considerable amount of time given our workload. It's a large project. We use a mix of linux servers and baked windows ami images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly create Amazon EC2 instances and then Stop them, making the available to Start later. As you point out, this has the benefit that instances will Start faster than they take to Launch a new instance.

**There is no automated method to assist with this.** You could have to code a solution that does the following:

- **Monitor** the number of Stopped instances
- If the quantity is below the threshold, **launch** a new instance
- The new instance could automatically **stop itself via User Data** (either via a Shutdown command to the Operating System, or via a `StopInstances` call to EC2)

Some things you would have to consider:

- What **triggers** the monitoring? Would it be on a schedule?
- The task that launches a new instance would need to **wait** for the new instance to Launch & Stop before launching any more instances
- What **Starts** the instances when they are needed?
- Do instances ever get **Stopped** when they are no longer required?

The much better choice would be to use **Auto Scaling**, with a scale-out alarm based on some metric that says your fleet is busy, and a scale-in alarm to remove instances when the fleet is not busy. The scale-out alarm could be set to launch instances once a threshold is passed (eg 80% CPU) that should allow the new instance(s) to launch before things are 100% busy. The time difference between launching a new instance and starting an existing instance is quite small (at least for Linux).

If you're using Windows, the biggest time delay when launching a new instance is due to **Sysprep**, which makes a "clean" machine with new Unique IDs. You could cheat by creating an AMI without Sysprep, which would boot faster.

Comment: Thanks @John Rotenstein. We currently have a coded solution that waits for the state to change. I wasn't aware that user data could be used for this, and I was most certainly not aware of Sysprep. Excellent answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding your objective... you can't "ensure availability" of instances without paying for them.

Instances in the stopped state are only logical entities that don't physically exist anywhere -- hardware is allocated on launch, deallocated on stop, reallocated on the next start.  In the unlikely condition where an availability zone is exhausted of capacity for given instance class, stopped instances of that class won't start, because there is no hardware available for them to be deployed onto.

To ensure that instances are always available, you have to reserve them, and you have to specify the reservations in a specific availability zone:

> Amazon EC2 Reserved Instances provide a significant discount (up to 75%) compared to On-Demand pricing **and provide a capacity reservation** when used in a specific Availability Zone. *[emphasis added]*
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/reserved-instances/

Under most plans, reserved instances are billed the same rate whether they are running or not, so there would be little point in stopping them.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. I want to maintain a certain amount of instances per region that are in a 'stopped' state. Let's suppose this number is 10. Each time one of these instances is 'started', I want to create another instance, which is stopped once it's 'running'. That's it.

Comment: How is that plan more useful/helpful than just launching instances when you need them?  What is the benefit of that strategy?

Comment: We are now going off-topic, but I'll indulge. When autoscaling, the time it takes to start a stopped instance is significantly shorter than the time it takes to create an equivalent instance.